# Can I use Intellij J IDEA for android application development?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I have a question about most of the android developers now a days using Android Studio as the IDE for developing android apps. I'm using Intellij J IDEA as my IDE for developing java desktop apps. Is there any plugin to extend Intellij J IDEA IDE to develop android apps?

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio is the same as Intellij Idea. Design is the only difference between them. Use android studio

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I'll check it!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Android Studio since it is based on IntelliJ

Comment: please add details .

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean a Download Link?

Comment: @r3fresh_ Thank you , I'll check the links for android studio!